# Python3: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'train.txt', even with complete path

Tags: python, file, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently working with Python3 on Jupyter Notebook. I try to load a text file which is in the exact same directory as my python notebook but it still doesn't find it. My line of code is:
    `text_data = prepare_text('train.txt')`

and the error is a typical
    `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'train.txt'`

I've already tried to enter the full path to my text file but then I still get the same error.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows ?

Comment: Try an `os.listdir()` to see what Python sees in the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Windows put a secont `.txt` at the end of the file name, so I should have used `train.txt.txt` instead.

Comment: After searching for three days, I found this solution and it solved my problem. I think how adding extra `.txt` solves this problem must be highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just writing `prepare_text("train.txt")`, try giving the complete path of that file for eg- `prepare_text("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\Project\\train.txt")`. If the by giving the full path it works, then you must have not changed the directory to your python notebook.
Other solution could be by adding this code on the very first line of your code-

```
import os
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\Project\\")
```